# Facebook login using api's

Tags: facebook

I have one website and i'm trying to achieve the following please help me 
I want to login to facebook from my website. i know the username and password of user can i login at the server using facebook api's for that user and use that session on the person viewing my site. 
My site has a facebook button when user clicks on it i have to open facebook page on different browser tab with that user logged in.
please suggest

Comment: Are you asking how can a person log into Facebook by providing username password at your site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the starting point of using Facebook API

http://developers.facebook.com/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Facebook_authentication_in_Windows_Phone_application

**Update:** Login Implementation

[ASP.NET Implementation](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/04/aspnet-integrate-facebook-login.html)

[ASP.NET MVC4 Implementation](http://blog.ntotten.com/2012/12/19/facebook-authentication-with-the-facebook-c-sdk-and-asp-net-mvc-4/)

Comment: I have seen this and tried a lot but i need this specific thing to be done. The site has a facebook button and when user clicks on it. it should open a new browser tab and login automatically i have user name and password on my website server.

Comment: @sumeetkumar See my updated answer for the implementation

Comment: @sumeetkumar what I am guessing is that you are trying to auto fill the fields of username and password which is not right